# Setter methods get fired before actionListener method

Tags: richfaces

```
<a4j:commandButton id="viewTemplate" value="select" 
actionListener="#{msgCustomizationMgmtBean.viewMsgContent}" 
ajaxSingle="true" reRender="reviewArea">
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item.id}" target="#{backingBean.selectTmpId}"/></a4j:commandButton>
```

i use f:setPropertyActionListener to pass value into backing bean, but i found it got fire after actionListener method. is there anyway to make fire before it. like following sequence.
1. set backing value.
2. method get new set value and perform operation.

thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of your f:setPropertyActionListener you should use:

```
<a4j:actionparam name="setViewMode"
   assignTo="#{backingBean.selectTmpId}"
   value="#{item.id}"/>
```

It's better to use ajax4jsf controls togheter with its related controls than with jsf components.

Comment: Even if you wrap `a4j:actionparam` with an `a4j:support` with `event=onclick`?

Comment: Hi Christian, it works with even=onclick. following is working code for this problem based on your solution. thank you very much
<a4j:commandButton value="delete" >
 <a4j:support event="onclick" reRender="reviewArea">
  <a4j:actionparam name="setViewMode" assignTo="#{backingBean.selectTmpId}" value="#{item.id}" actionListener="#{backingBean.viewMsgContent}" />
 </a4j:support>
</a4j:commandButton>

Comment: @Tsung Lin Tsai - Glad to hear that;)

Comment: There's no need to use `a4j:support`. Just moving `actionListener` from `a4j:commandButton` to `a4j:actionparam` solves this problem. RichFaces 3.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

If you use large objects as action-property, this may help you:

```
<a4j:commandButton action="dia_ok" actionListener="#{projectBean.dias.doDelete}" id="deleteScreenshot" reRender="panelTitle" value="Loeschen">
  <a4j:support event="onclick" ajaxSingle="true">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{projectBean.dias.selected}" value="#{dia}" />
  </a4j:support>
</a4j:commandButton>
```

(a4j:actionparam will crash on reference-loop between object-instances [RF-2576](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-2576))